# How can I add a JTextField to a JFrame's MenuBar?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I've been trying to overload JMenu and put in some custom code to support a JTextField but that isn't going well.  My main purpose here is to add a search field to the right of my menu items.  So I have something like File, Edit, help on the left and then on the right would be the search bar, almost like how there is a google search bar in some browsers.  Does anyone have an idea how I could go about adding this functionality?

Comment: Why isn't it going well? What *specifically* seems to be troubling you?

Comment: @mre I've run into a dead end where I'm trying to add the text box instead of a button.  JMenuItem inherits from AbstractButton so I don't know how to add a text box instead of just changing the text on an AbstractButton.  I also don't believe this is the best way to add the functionality I'm talking about because it seems I may have to change around a bunch of stuff deep within JMenu.  I guess I'm looking for guidance on a better way to do this then what I'm currently trying to do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I never see that as `JMenuItem`, I think that alyways placed in `JMenuBar`

[image]

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuGlueDemo {

    public MenuGlueDemo() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(createMenu("Menu 1"));
        menuBar.add(createMenu("Menu 2"));
        menuBar.add(createMenu("Menu 3"));
        menuBar.add(new JSeparator());
        menuBar.add(new JButton("   Seach ....  "));
        menuBar.add(new JTextField("   Seach ....  "));
        menuBar.add(new JComboBox(new Object[]{"height", "length", "volume"}));
        menuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        menuBar.add(createMenu("About"));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuGlueDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(menuBar);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JMenu createMenu(String title) {
        JMenu m = new JMenu(title);
        m.add("Menu item #1 in " + title);
        m.add("Menu item #2 in " + title);
        m.add("Menu item #3 in " + title);
        if (title.equals("About")) {
            m.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MenuGlueDemo menuGlueDemo = new MenuGlueDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more then once, thank you for another excellent answer!

Comment: you are welcome, glad to help +1, and not easy job to put any JComponent to the JMenuItem, I used for that only JDialog/JWindow (GridLayout) with added JComponents

Comment: Did you mean `"Search"` instead of `"Seach"`?

Comment: @Cool Guy probably inadequate intensity of light at end of my tunnel, too :-)