# Get "fat header" background color in Swing

Tags: java, swing, gtk

I'm building a Swing app in which I'd like to put a "fat header" as in this image:

[image]

Is there a nice way to get the native system colour for that background area? So on Ubuntu with a default theme I'd like to get the colour in the image, but for other themes, and on Windows, I'd also like to have something sensible. I'm using the native Look & Feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FatHeader is probably `JMenuBar`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127463/714968) or `JPanel` with `GradientPaint` (very simple is take this `Gradient[]` from `JButton's JComponents`)

Comment: Maybe `UIManager` property "MenuBar.background"?

Comment: [Gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5845007/714968) and looks like this is only [modifications of XxxButtonUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968)

Comment: I know how to build the bar, what I need is the correct background colour.

Comment: Oh, I see JMenuBar comes with that colour by default, and I can add any components (not just menus) to it.