# Add JTextField to JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jtoolbar

I'm trying to add `JTextField` to `JToolBar` and it works, but it is too long. I need it to take only 3 letters.

Here is the screenshot of it now...
[image: screenshot]

I tried following methods,

```
JTextField field = new JextField(3); // thought this limits to three characters.
```

And I tried,

```
field.setColumns(3); // this didn't work either.
```

Comment: Interesting. :)  Over on Nimbus L&F, you get the opposite behaviour - the text field is always the preferred size and it's difficult to make it grow wider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default layout of a tool-bar respects the maximum size set for a text field.

[image: Text Field in Tool Bar]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextFieldInToolBar {

    TextFieldInToolBar() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
        p.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        Icon disk = (Icon)UIManager.get("FileView.floppyDriveIcon"); 
        Icon pc = (Icon)UIManager.get("FileView.computerIcon"); 
        tb.add(new JButton(disk));
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(3);
        tf.setMaximumSize(tf.getPreferredSize());
        tb.add(tf);
        tb.addSeparator();
        tb.add(new JButton(pc));

        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TextFieldInToolBar();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"no upvotes for today"*  Me too! *"but why bothering with JToolBar"* Why not?  I'm bored & wanted to see if it could be as simple as setting a maximum size.  ;)

Comment: no offense but I saw there issue with height direction, why not use FlowLayout / BoxLayout directly

Comment: Wow, this is great. It kinda cleaner than previous.

Comment: I am for the strike, (persuade John and nice animal too) two weeks without upvotes in the Swing tagged posts, this will be another jokes hehehe

Comment: If you want the maximum size always the same as the preferred size, you should extend JTextField and override getMaximumSize(). If you don't, Swing will think you're setting the maximum size explicitly and even if the preferred size changes later, won't update the maximum size to match. Another way to do it is to handle it in your updateUI() method from some other component.

Comment: @Trejkaz  Yes, that is a good point to override rather than set.  I might update the source.  See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1):

- [JToolBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) is container as [JFrame, JDialog or JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), you can laying this container by using the proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- this issue should be the same by using [JMenuBar as container for JComponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127463/714968) (alternative)

Comment: Thank you, but is there any solution, second point link shows that there is no solution.

Comment: advantage of using JToolBar is dockable container, but this is for me dis_advantate and looks very ugly

Comment: So your suggestion is to use JMenuBar, I already have one menubar, isn't it a problem?

Comment: no you can place another JMenuBar to the NORTH area into JFrame (for example) or to the JPanel e.g.

Comment: I solved similair issue by put three JPanel(setOpaque(false)) left and right by using GridLayout center JPanel (JTextField and JLabel) by BorderLayout,