# How do I place two JMenuItems adjacent to each other?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

My Code:

```
JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit circle");
JMenuItem help = new JMenuItem("Help");
JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

bar.add(menu);
bar.add(help);
bar.add(exit);
```

Output of the `JMenuBar`:

[image: OUTPUT]

I want the output to be something like this:

[image: EXPECTED_OUTPUT]

What do I need to do in order to get the expected output?

Comment: If it were me - I'd put `Help` then a menu separator, then `Exit` in an `Application` (or similar) `JMenu` and add it to the left of the `Edit circle` menu..  I can't see that adding menu items directly to a `JMenuBar` will work out well, as your experiments suggest.

Comment: `Help` and `Exit` are not `JMenu`s, they should be added to a `JMenu` and that should be added to the `JMenuBar`

Comment: @MadProgrammer , So, adding `JMenuItem` to a `JMenuBar` won't work? But I have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255798/how-do-i-place-two-jmenuitems-adjacent-to-each-other#comment48612165_30256074) now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson , Ok. Good idea. I'll go with that if I don't find any other way to solve my problem.

Comment: @CoolGuy Oh, it works, but as you say, it doesn't work the way you want it to

Comment: again JToolBar and now JMenuBar has BoxLayout

Comment: @mKorbel , I didn't know that a layout can be applied to `JMenuBar`. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @Cool Guy you didn't read, to try code linked my comment sticked to question posted by different OP

Comment: @mKorbel . Umm. Which? [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237571/how-to-move-a-rectangle-with-arrow-keys#comment48577445_30237837)?

Comment: @Cool Guy [good one - sorry:-)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8127463/714968) aaaah [my mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196854/jseperator-in-jtoolbar-moves-the-components-to-right-end#comment48500252_30196854)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot add `JMenuItem` in `JMenuBar`.
so try this.. it'll work..

```
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Edit circle");
    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenu exit = new JMenu("Exit");
    bar.add(menu1);
    bar.add(help);
    bar.add(exit);
    exit.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Exiting");
        }

        @Override
        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

you cannot add `ActionListener` to JMenu. use `MenuListener`..

reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862165/jmenu-actionlistener)...

Comment: This produced the expected output, but now, the pressing `help` and `exit` doesn't do anything. I've added `ActionListener`s to both of them. :(

Comment: `ActinoListener` will not work on `JMenu`.. for that you have to use `JMenuItem` or you can add `MenuListener` to `exit` menu...check the code...

Comment: I ended up using `mouseListener`. Thanks for the help anyway.